# IntelliJ IDEA: Argument name/hint in method call

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

[image]

That gray blob right before `0`. Please identify the feature, and, if possible, tell how to change the color of this hint.

*I'm a fan of JetBrains IDEs, but only occasionally I use Java. Seen this feature some time ago, but totally forgot what it is :(*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a *parameter name hint*. These can be disabled for that constructor with an intention (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) on the parameter itself or in `Settings | Editor | General | Appearance`. The color of the hint can be changed in `Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Language Defaults | Inline parameter hint`.

Comment: Very thorough answer :) I was definitely checking ```Language defaults```, don't know how I missed it.

Comment: If this doesn't disable parameter name hints for you, you can disable them in Settings > Editor > Parameter Name Hints