# How to disable parameter hints in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Does anybody know what is this?

[image]

And how can I turn it off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA: Weird hint in method/constructor call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013050/intellij-idea-weird-hint-in-method-constructor-call)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's called [parameter hints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfYOddEmaRw).

Can be disabled here:

[image: hints]

Comment: I unchecked it (actually it was never checked to begin with)... I am still getting these hints when I run the debugger, should I file a bug report?

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover If you are sure that these are indeed parameter hints, file a new issue.

Comment: Then what else are they? I just started using IntelliJ IDEA, yesterday... I could send you a new screenshot but I refrained because I didn't want to post duplicates. That checkbox was "unchecked" from the get go. With your permission, can I edit my original post with a new screenshot?

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover Just [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the screenshot of the problem and stop hijacking other's questions.

Comment: I wasn't hijacking with all due respect - when I first posted it, I didn't know they were called "hints". I used a different terminology, "labels", and then I figured out they were hints so I changed my post accordingly just to be diligent. Sorry, if someone else wrote a similar question that I never came across.

Comment: If this doesn't disable parameter name hints for you, you can disable them in Settings > Editor > Parameter Name Hints

Comment: For me it was in Editor > Inlay Hints > Parameters

Answer (score 26):

Since IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 these are called "Inlay Hints". [See help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints.html) for more info

[image: IntelliJ IDEA | Settings > Editor > Inlay hints]