# What are these un-editable words/letters in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Before some strings, it says `s:` or `path:`. What are these?

Picture

[image: idk]

Comment: It would appear to be the name of the parameter

Comment: njzk is right. Those are parameter names. It's new in the last 2016 release.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346480/how-to-disable-parameter-hints-in-intellij-idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `method parameter name hints` telling what argument name is from the method definition that's being called:

You can disable them by <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and type `hints` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent versions of **IntelliJ** just right click on the name *(as you can look at in the picture `pathname:`)*, and choose `Disable Parameter Name Hints`, this will hide the the word `Parameter name hints` in the method definitions.

[image]